# twilio say something to caller (node.js)

Tags: node.js, twilio

Hey guys I am working on something and have following Problem :

ACTUAL AIM  - If someone calls, I want to let the voice say: "Try to reach someone" and then call some numbers out of an array. ( cant do that atm because i need to fake a call )

ATM AIM - Thats why I at least want to say something to the one who answers the twilio call, that I can be sure it "would" work.

So i faked a call by sending the url that twilio would send (if it gets a call) via a localhost http server. So far so good, my phone gets called. But the woman dont say what I wanted her to say... She sais : Thank you for trying our documentation and then waiting music is following.

AND: The call.status is ALLWAYS queued, or I dont catch it at the right place :/ , Remember my phone is ringing so it should have at least the status ringing ...

This is what I have at the moment:

requestHandler.js:

```
    var querystring = require("querystring");
var emergency = require("./emergency");
var twilio = require('twilio');

function callRequest(response) {
    var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    resp.say({voice:'woman'}, 'ahoy hoy! Testing Twilio and node.js');

    console.log("call incomming ! EMERGENCY 1 1 11 !");

    //emergency.handleIncommingCall();
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/xml"});
    response.end(resp.toString());
}

exports.callRequest = callRequest;
```

server.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    route(handle, pathname, response, request);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(1337);
  console.log("Server has started");
}

exports.start = start;
exports.http = http;
```

router.js:

```
function route(handle, pathname, response, request) {
  console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
  if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
    handle[pathname](response, request);
  }else{
    console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("404 Not found");
    response.end();
  }
}

exports.route = route;
```

index.js:

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandler = require("./requestHandler");

var handle = { };
handle["/demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/"] = requestHandler.callRequest;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

emergency.js:

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var accountSid = 'cant tell ya';
var authToken = "cant tell ya";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
var firstCascadeNumber = "cant tell ya";
var secondCascadeNumber;
var privateNumber; //enter privateNumber here
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

function handleIncommingCall (){
    //twilio should say : we contact team internet pls wait
    //twilio should make music
    call(1,firstCascadeNumber);
        //cb if staus ist nicht rangegangen call(2)
}

function call (cascade,cascadeNumber){
    client.makeCall({
        url: "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
        to: cascadeNumber,
        from: "cant tell ya" 
    }, function(err, call) {
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR:", err.message);
        }else{
            console.log("calling " + cascadeNumber);
            console.log("status: " + call.status);
            if(cascade == 1){
                //twiml.say("Hello this i a test. Thank you for calling.");
                console.log("should say what i want it to say ! god damn it ");
                console.log("status: " + call.status);
                //if user geht ran
                    //startConference()
                //if user geht nicht ran
                    //call(2,secondCascadeNumber)
            }else if(cascade == 2){
                //if user geht ran
                    //startConference()
                //if user geht nicht ran
                    //inform caller that no one is there
            }else{
                console.log("Error: cascade doesnt exsist");
            }
        }
    });
}

function openConference(call,from,to){
    //call.joinConference([roomName, option, cbOnEnd])
}

exports.handleIncommingCall = handleIncommingCall;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're most of the way there, but you've not quite set your application out right here.

When you make the call, the callback you get only refers to whether the call started correctly. It is not a callback that you need to return TwiML to in order to tell Twilio what to do with the call.

Instead, what happens is when Twilio makes the call, it will send an HTTP request to the URL you supply when you make the call in the first place. That URL should be in your application and available to Twilio.

This blog post on [using Twilio with Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html) should be able to show you what I mean by all of that and set you up with a good way of testing this locally too.

**Edit**

Thanks for updating your code.

Your problem is that you are not telling Twilio to ask you what to do with the call once it connects.

When you create a call with the API you need 3 parameters, the number to call, the number to call from and a URL. When Twilio connects the call it will make an HTTP request to the URL you supply asking what to do next and this is where you supply some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do with the call.

Currently you are supplying this URL: http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml

If you click through the demo Twilio URL there, you will see the TwiML that is being returned and why you hear a message you are not expecting. Because the URL is not yours, your application cannot take control of the call.

You need to send a URL that points at a route in your application, and that route needs to respond with the TwiML you want. You can expose your local server to Twilio using a tool called [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) which will allow you to test this.

I recommend you follow the tutorial I linked before, this tutorial on [using ngrok to text your incoming HTTP requests from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html) and this [tutorial on creating a click to call application with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/node/express).

In the case of your application, instead of trying to handle "/demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/" which is not a URL you have control of, you should handle, say:

```
var handle = { };
handle["/calls"] = requestHandler.callRequest;
```

and then use ngrok to create a tunnel to your application and pass the URL to `client.makeCall` like this:

```
function call (cascade,cascadeNumber){
    client.makeCall({
        url: "http://YOUR_NGROK_SUBDOMAIN.ngrok.io/calls",
        to: cascadeNumber,
        from: "cant tell ya" 
    }, function(err, call) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Call could not be made", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Call created successfully. Call ID:", call.sid);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: So I did the tutorial and i actually get the xml document, but if I get the call is still get the same problem ... Have an Idea why?

Comment: What does your code look like now? And are you using ngrok to make your local web server public to the Internet?

Comment: Could you edit your question with your current code?

Comment: I did :) I think maybe the problem is the way i use xml, I dont know how to combine different reactions with the xml sending and my function.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look and do read through the tutorials I suggest as they will help you get to a solution quicker.

Comment: Thank you so far !

Comment: I found an other problem and I need to solve this first, could take a while :/

Comment: So Yeah this works but it creates an endless loop of calls... because if you trigger the call by clicking the link, the function is called and the url will be called again ... So what url shell I actually use there ?

Comment: What link are you clicking?

Comment: As i said, Twilio sends an URL if a special Number is called. For example call.com/incomming ... so if this url is called my server call my mobile because of the function call. in this function i need a url parameter for make call, and i used there the same url , then the loop begins. if i place there a test url ( no 404 , a test site ) then i get this ERROR: Url is not a valid URL

Comment: Ok, so don't use the same URL. The URL you need to use when making the call is one that will get called back to when the call is answered, so you need to return TwiML from that URL, as you do in your `callRequest` function above.

Comment: I have new Problems now, shell I make a new Question ?

Comment: Yeah, a new question is the best idea.